# lint: command not found

Tags: command-line, programming, c, coreutils, tee

Does Ubuntu have a lint utility?  How is it installed?

> In computer programming, lint is a Unix utility..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29

```
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ gcc program.c -o prog
program.c:5:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 main()
 ^
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ ./prog

Hello World

thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ lint program.c
No command 'lint' found, did you mean:
 Command 'line' from package 'util-linux' (main)
 Command 'jlint' from package 'jlint' (universe)
 Command 'link' from package 'coreutils' (main)
 Command 'dlint' from package 'dlint' (universe)
 Command 'lift' from package 'lift' (universe)
 Command 'tint' from package 'tint' (universe)
 Command 'hlint' from package 'hlint' (universe)
lint: command not found
thufir@mordor:~$
```

I'm trying to use lint as so:

> lint program.c | tee program.lint
>
> This displays the standard output of the command lint program.c at the
>   computer, and at the same time saves a copy of it in the file
>   program.lint. If a file named program.lint already exists, it is
>   deleted and replaced.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29#Unix-like_2

The manpage which wikipedia references is for BSD, I can't find a manpage for the Linux variant.  Do I need to install it, perhaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/632057/2072269?

Answer (score 16):

See `splint` - a GPL rewrite of `lint`.

However, `splint` does not fully support C99.

It is recommended to use `cppcheck`.

Answer (score 8):

From `apt-cache search lint`

> splint - tool for statically checking C programs for bugs.
>   splint-data - tool for statically checking C programs for bugs - data files
>   splint-doc-html - tool for statically checking C programs for bugs - HTML documentation

#### Installation

```
sudo apt-get install splint
```

#### Documentation

For documentation, examples and the downloads, check their website at http://www.splint.org.